# Swift - Convert Milliseconds to Date

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate

I have a data structure that contains timestamps in milliseconds such as 1470075992. I would like to convert this to a date only i.e. example 24/12/2016 without keeping the additional details that results from converting.

What function can I use to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Comment: That value is not milliseconds, it is seconds.

Comment: 1470075992 *milliseconds* after the epoch is Jan 18 00:21:16 GMT 1970, and 1470075992 *seconds* after the epoch is Aug  1 18:26:32 GMT 2016. So either the timestamp is in seconds, or the example is chosen badly.

Comment: var date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: (1477593000000 / 1000.0))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update for Swift 3.0:**

```
typealias UnixTime = Int

extension UnixTime {
    private func formatType(form: String) -> DateFormatter {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = form
        return dateFormatter
    }
    var dateFull: Date {
        return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(self))
    }
    var toHour: String {
        return formatType(form: "HH:mm").string(from: dateFull)
    }
    var toDay: String {
        return formatType(form: "MM/dd/yyyy").string(from: dateFull)
    }
}

var myMilliseconds: UnixTime = 1470075992
print(myMilliseconds.toDay)
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the simple clear extension

Comment: As a suggesion. Do not forget about time zones!

Answer (score 1):

Derive the NSDate from the timestamp in the normal way: divide by 1000 to get seconds and use an NSDate initializer as appropriate to get the date based on seconds from a given reference date, such as `init(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:)`.

The other part of your question makes no sense. You cannot do this "without keeping the additional details". There is no such thing as a "date only i.e. example 24/12/2016". A date is a date (an NSDate); it is a number of seconds, plain and simple. If you want to *see* only the day, month, and year of that date, that is a *string*, not a date, and making it is the job of an NSDateFormatter.

Comment: It does make sense, the concept of a date (not a precise number of seconds) exists in other programming languages. The name `NSDate` is misleading since it's not only a date, but also a time.

Comment: @Kametrixom it doesn't make sense for `NSDate`. You can't have an date without knowing the time of day, because depending on the timezone of the user, the NSDate will have a different "day" value. If you really want just a set of day/month/year, you can use `NSDateComponents` or (in Swift) a tuple.

Comment: @matt `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:` assumes the timestamp is in UTC time, which is not a safe assumption and could provide a date off by an entire day.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Agreed. I didn't say to use `init(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:)`. I said use an initializer to form the date from the number of seconds, and I gave an example of an initializer; I have no idea how the OP's milliseconds are reckoned in relation to real time, as the OP did not reveal that.

Comment: @matt fair enough. I think you should have highlighted timezones specifically. Also, the second paragraph is incorrect... NSDateComponents is available, and provides a date without a time. Apple uses throughout EventKit for example, and it is ideal where you want the data to match the user interface rather than a mathematically "correct" date.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert "NSDateComponents is available, and provides a date without a time" No it doesn't. You can form a date without supplying time components, but the resulting NSDate does have a time (midnight). And anyway that has nothing to do with the OP's issue; he has no date components at all. If you think my answer is bad, please supply your own better answer — don't nag me about my answer, because I'm not going to change it.